# VBA code to automatic produce charts in excel

Tags: vba, excel, plot, charts

I am trying to write a vba code in excel to produce automatic plots of many groups of data.

I have tried the following script but I am facing the difficulty of iterating throug the columns (x-axis, y-ayis of the plot/chart).

The first par of the code is copied from another tag from here and is supposed to give the relation between the column number and name (i.e. Column number 33 = AG).

My questions are:

1. It is better to pick the region and apply the macro or to write the macro for the exact field of interest
2. Have anyone an idea how can iterate through the columns/ groups?

An example of my data-set (here only 3 groups are presented; the first column is the y-axis, the first row is the titles of the legend, the next 13 columns are the x-axes):

```
    dw=0,01 dw=0,1  dw=1    dw=2    dw=3    dw=4    dw=5    dw=6    dw=8    dw=10   dw=20   dw=30   dw=40
0,0 0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000
0,1 0,4011  0,4057  0,4465  0,4827  0,5119  0,5359  0,5561  0,5732  0,6006  0,6215  0,6786  0,7027  0,7146
0,2 0,5523  0,5553  0,5810  0,6029  0,6199  0,6332  0,6438  0,6522  0,6643  0,6720  0,6796  0,6682  0,6519
0,3 0,6290  0,6286  0,6245  0,6195  0,6143  0,6089  0,6035  0,5980  0,5870  0,5762  0,5256  0,4818  0,4440
0,4 0,6726  0,6689  0,6351  0,6038  0,5774  0,5546  0,5347  0,5169  0,4862  0,4605  0,3705  0,3114  0,2672
0,5 0,6843  0,6778  0,6199  0,5677  0,5248  0,4887  0,4578  0,4310  0,3866  0,3511  0,2403  0,1787  0,1375
0,6 0,6656  0,6574  0,5840  0,5185  0,4653  0,4211  0,3839  0,3520  0,3002  0,2599  0,1432  0,0862  0,0520
0,7 0,6135  0,6045  0,5256  0,4556  0,3991  0,3526  0,3137  0,2806  0,2276  0,1871  0,0757  0,0267  0,0014
0,8 0,5220  0,5137  0,4400  0,3750  0,3227  0,2798  0,2441  0,2139  0,1660  0,1297  0,0333  0,0060  0,0252
0,9 0,3632  0,3571  0,3033  0,2559  0,2178  0,1867  0,1609  0,1391  0,1046  0,0787  0,0113  0,0145  0,0266
1,0 0,2435  0,2393  0,2026  0,1703  0,1443  0,1232  0,1056  0,0908  0,0674  0,0499  0,0046  0,0121  0,0198

    dw=0,01 dw=0,1  dw=1    dw=2    dw=3    dw=4    dw=5    dw=6    dw=8    dw=10   dw=20   dw=30   dw=40
0,0 0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000
0,1 0,3015  0,3059  0,3454  0,3820  0,4126  0,4386  0,4610  0,4804  0,5124  0,5378  0,6116  0,6464  0,6656
0,2 0,4161  0,4195  0,4497  0,4771  0,4994  0,5178  0,5331  0,5460  0,5661  0,5808  0,6118  0,6140  0,6066
0,3 0,4742  0,4751  0,4831  0,4896  0,4940  0,4969  0,4986  0,4995  0,4990  0,4967  0,4720  0,4417  0,4122
0,4 0,5074  0,5058  0,4911  0,4765  0,4635  0,4516  0,4406  0,4304  0,4120  0,3956  0,3314  0,2842  0,2469
0,5 0,5165  0,5128  0,4792  0,4475  0,4204  0,3969  0,3761  0,3577  0,3262  0,3001  0,2134  0,1616  0,1256
0,6 0,5026  0,4975  0,4513  0,4083  0,3721  0,3412  0,3144  0,2910  0,2520  0,2207  0,1254  0,0761  0,0457
0,7 0,4634  0,4577  0,4061  0,3585  0,3188  0,2851  0,2562  0,2312  0,1900  0,1577  0,0645  0,0214  0,0034
0,8 0,3945  0,3890  0,3400  0,2949  0,2574  0,2258  0,1989  0,1757  0,1378  0,1084  0,0267  0,0084  0,0260
0,9 0,2746  0,2705  0,2344  0,2012  0,1737  0,1506  0,1309  0,1140  0,0866  0,0654  0,0077  0,0154  0,0266
1,0 0,1841  0,1814  0,1566  0,1339  0,1151  0,0993  0,0859  0,0744  0,0557  0,0413  0,0025  0,0125  0,0197

    dw=0,01 dw=0,1  dw=1    dw=2    dw=3    dw=4    dw=5    dw=6    dw=8    dw=10   dw=20   dw=30   dw=40
0,0 0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000  0,0000
0,1 0,0851  0,0873  0,1081  0,1293  0,1487  0,1665  0,1830  0,1983  0,2257  0,2497  0,3356  0,3891  0,4260
0,2 0,1198  0,1218  0,1414  0,1611  0,1789  0,1950  0,2098  0,2232  0,2468  0,2669  0,3325  0,3664  0,3849
0,3 0,1375  0,1388  0,1511  0,1633  0,1742  0,1838  0,1924  0,2000  0,2129  0,2233  0,2512  0,2584  0,2566
0,4 0,1480  0,1485  0,1529  0,1571  0,1606  0,1635  0,1659  0,1678  0,1706  0,1723  0,1701  0,1600  0,1475
0,5 0,1514  0,1512  0,1486  0,1458  0,1430  0,1403  0,1376  0,1350  0,1298  0,1248  0,1023  0,0834  0,0675
0,6 0,1480  0,1472  0,1396  0,1317  0,1245  0,1178  0,1116  0,1058  0,0954  0,0862  0,0523  0,0303  0,0148
0,7 0,1370  0,1359  0,1254  0,1148  0,1052  0,0964  0,0883  0,0809  0,0679  0,0567  0,0186  0,0037  0,0169
0,8 0,1171  0,1159  0,1050  0,0940  0,0841  0,0751  0,0669  0,0595  0,0464  0,0353  0,0011  0,0195  0,0302
0,9 0,0817  0,0809  0,0724  0,0640  0,0564  0,0496  0,0434  0,0377  0,0279  0,0196  0,0064  0,0196  0,0268
1,0 0,0550  0,0543  0,0485  0,0426  0,0374  0,0326  0,0283  0,0244  0,0176  0,0119  0,0056  0,0145  0,0192
```

And here is the code as it seems right now:

```
Sub Makro3()
'
' Makro3 Makro
'The next lines give the column number to iterate for:
    Dim i&, k&, j&
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim name As String
    d = colNum
    name = ""
    Do While (d > 0)
        m = (d - 1) Mod 26
        name = Chr(65 + m) + name
        d = Int((d - m) / 26)
    Loop
    GetColumnName = name
' The next lines should give the chart commants:
For i = 1 To 20
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm ""i"").IncrementLeft 445.9090551181
    'here the next chart should be designed below the prior chart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Diagramm ""i"").IncrementTop i * 10  
    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (1)
    ' iterate through the columns for each group of series
    For k = 1 To 13
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ' the name of the column i.e. AH69
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(k).Name = "=linear!$AH$68"
    ' the x-axis changes with increasing column number
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(k).XValues = "=linear!$AH$69:$AH$79"
    ' the y-axis changes with increasing group set
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(k).Values = "=linear!$AG$69:$AG$79"
    Next k
    ' script lines to define the format of the chart, axes, etc...
    With
    ......
    End With
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Select
Next i
End Sub
```

With this script I am expecting 3 charts, with 13 curves each. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the address of the first cell (on the left of `dw=0,01`) of the data?

Comment: `"Diagramm ""i""` what is this supposed to be?

Comment: *I am expecting 3 charts* - In these two lines `For i = 1 To 20
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select` ..  20 charts will be added!

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman yes, you are right, with my script will be added 20 charts, but for the data given only 3. The script was not rewritten for the data given.

Comment: @A.S.H, I tried to escape the double quotes in order to iterate the chart numbering.

Comment: @R3uK In my script the dw=0,01 is the cell AH68 but it can be taken as the B1, too. A2 would be then the value 0,0

Comment: Is your data static as shown in the sample or the number of groups and series may change (i.e. there will be more than 3 charts and/or with more than 13 series)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be a lot simpler than the way you are going about it. See the code below, based on the example data you gave.

I made the following assumptions:

1. Data starts in cell A1
2. Sheet name is "Sheet1"
3. Data set is exactly as provided (with one line space between each set

From these assumptions you can change all counting and sheet/range references to your exact needs.

```
Sub MakeCharts()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 38 Step 13

    ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select

    With ActiveChart

        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

        Dim k As Integer

        For k = 1 To 13

            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(k).Name = ws.Cells(x, k + 1)
            .SeriesCollection(k).XValues = ws.Range(ws.Cells(x + 1, k + 1), ws.Cells(x + 11, k + 1))
            .SeriesCollection(k).Values = ws.Range(ws.Cells(x + 1, 1), ws.Cells(x + 11, 1))

        Next

        .ApplyLayout (1)

        Dim sName As String
        sName = Replace(.Name, ws.Name & " ", "")

    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(sName)
        .IncrementLeft 445.9090551181
        .IncrementTop x * 10
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This works good but it is not 100% what I needed. My problem is that the x-data are in columns (the 13 columns left to the numbers 0,0-0,1-0,2-0,3-....1,0, which are the values of the y-axis. But it is a good basis to start with. Thank you.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Try the edited code. I set it up to place the XValues and YValues as needed.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need! Thank you! You saved me from a lot of effort!

Comment: I noticed that at the legend appear more datalines than the ones designed (instead of 13 curves at the legend appear 23 data lines). I cannot find why. Can you debug this issue?

Comment: please submit a separate question with the exact code you are using. The code I built here only produced 13 legend keys.

Comment: @GeMa your are right, the code generates some series depending on the `activecell` location at the time of adding the chart. To ensure no series is generated move the `activecell` to an empty cell, suggest to include this line `ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 1).Activate ` before this line `ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select`.

Comment: good catch @EEM! Stated a different way, if the active cell is anywhere inside a region of data the line `ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select` will used that region as the data source.

Comment: @EEM & Scott Holtzman, you must both speak in another level, which I cannot understand. I add the suggested line and my active cell is an empty cell but the problem is still there...

Comment: try this instead and let us know `ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(2, 2).Activate`

Comment: or try this ...  `ws.Cells(1,ws.Columns.Count).Activate` ... then put this at the end `ws.UsedRange.Cells(1,1).Select` to move the sheet back in view of the data

Comment: The first one worked for me as the last cell of the `UsedRange` was blank, then I realized that in most cases the last cell will not be empty. Using `.Cells(2,2)` ensures the cell will always be empty and surrounded by empty cells.